# Multiprocessing code works upon import, breaks upon being called

Tags: python, import, multiprocessing, importerror, python-multiprocessing

In a file called `test.py` I have

```
print 'i am cow'
import multi4
print 'i am cowboy'
```

and in `multi4.py` I have

```
import multiprocessing as mp
manager = mp.Manager()
print manager
```

I am confused by the way this code operates.

At the command line, if I type `python` and then in the python environment if I type `import test.py` I get the expected behavior:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>>import test
i am cow
<multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager object at 0x025209B0>
i am cowboy 
>>>
```

However if I type `test.py` at the command line, I get

```
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
i am cow
```

Which would presumably go on forever unless I kill it. When I kill it, I get a bunch of repeated errors:

```
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 373, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 373, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So what is going on? Why does it behave one way under import, and another when I try to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multiprocessing` [won't work properly](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) in the interactive prompt on Windows, because it can't properly re-import `__main__` in the child processes it spawns. However, that actually  actually *helps* you here, since it keeps the `manager = mp.Manager()` line from being recursively executed in the child process that spawns when the `Manager` starts up.

In the actual script, however, the child can re-import `__main__` properly. You're seeing the infinite recursion because you're not protecting the call to `mp.Manager()` with an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, which is [required on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) to prevent `mp.Manager()` from being executed in the child when the re-import occurs:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = mp.Manager()
    print manager
```

**Edit:**

Your example, where your main script (test.py) imports the module that creates the `Manager`, needs a bit of refactoring. You need to instantiate the `Manager` from the main script, by calling a method in the module that actually uses `multiprocessing`:

```
print 'i am cow'
import multi4
if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi4.init_manager()
print 'i am cowboy'
```

**multi4.py**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
manager = None
def init_manager():
    global manager
    manager = mp.Manager()
```

This is the only way to make sure you only create the `Manager` when you're actually executing a script.

Comment: One thing though -- how can I be sure that the code in `multi4.py` is actually being executed? The manager object is not printing to the terminal, and when I change to `if name == 'multi4':` I get the same recursive behavior as before when calling `test.py` at the command line...

Comment: @Wapiti Ah, right, I missed this initially. You need to refactor your scripts a bit so that the `Manager` is instantiated by making a call in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard inside test.py. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Okay, the code above is definitely creating the manager, as I can see it if I embed a print command. However, it also produces the print commands *twice*. I cannot see why. Do you get the same behavior? It prints `i am cow i am cow i am cowboy i am cowboy`.

Comment: This appears to be a Windows issue. On the Mac it only prints cow and cowboy once.

Comment: @Wapiti Oh, it's happening because the `__main__` module (test.py) gets re-imported in the child, which means everything at the top level of that module gets executed twice; once in the parent, once in the child. Just move the prints inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to fix it.