# Multiprocessing not working with cmd2 module, import issue?

Tags: python, import, cmd, multiprocessing, importerror

Extending the solution from this question [Multiprocessing code works upon import, breaks upon being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909550/multiprocessing-code-works-upon-import-breaks-upon-being-called), I have injected some multiprocessing code into my project, which has promptly broken.

I think there are import issues. I have two modules. `test.py` looks like:

```
print 'omnia praeclara'
import multi4
if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi4.init_manager()
print 'rara sunt'
```

and `multi4.py` looks like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def add():
    print 2+2
def init_manager():
    proc = mp.Process(target=add)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```

Now, this code works fine. It produces the following when run from the command line (Windows):

```
omnia praeclara
omnia praeclara
rara sunt
4
rara sunt
```

Which is to be expected (the double printing is explained in the link above).

HOWEVER --- when I make `test.py` like this:

```
print 'omnia praeclara'
import multi4
if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi4.init_manager()
print 'rara sunt'   

import cmd2
class Prompt(cmd2.Cmd):

    def default(self, line):
        return cmd2.Cmd.default(self, line)
    prompt = '\n+++ '
    intro = '\n by that remembered or with that forgot.'
    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True

Prompt().cmdloop()
```

I get

```
omnia praeclara
omnia praeclara
rara sunt
by that remembered or with that forgot.
+++
```

This is the command prompt for the `cmd2` module. The process calling `add` does not produce anything. It is hung now. If I type `exit` into the prompt I get:

```
+++ exit
4
rara sunt

by that remembered or with that forgot.
+++
```

So the multiprocessing code finishes, but now I am *back into my cmd2 prompt!* It is only when I exit again that I really exit.

Clearly, everything is being imported twice. This was referenced in the above link, but is there any way to avoid this? More importantly, **how can I get my processes working in the background while I am doing things in `cmd2`?**

Comment: It's the same issue as before; you need to protect the entry point of test.py. Move the code that executes `Prompt().cmdloop()` under the `if__name__ == "__main__" :` guard so it doesn't get executed in the child as well as the parent.

Comment: You are a multiprocessing god.

Comment: My code and problem is hellsa more complex than what I've posted but you just solved the whole thing. Post as an answer and this multiprocessing n00b shall accept. I did not realize that how important it was to protect entry. Thanks.

Comment: @dano -  I know this is really inappropriate but could you look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926221/python-using-streamhandler-in-multiprocessing-environment

Comment: Ah, the burden of divinity...

Comment: @Beginner I added an answer to your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue that's causing the double printing - anything in `test.py` not protected by the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard will get executed in both the parent and child processes. You need to move the call to `Prompt().cmdloop()` under the guard to prevent it from being executed in the child:

```
print 'omnia praeclara'
import multi4

print 'rara sunt'   
import cmd2

class Prompt(cmd2.Cmd):

    def default(self, line):
        return cmd2.Cmd.default(self, line)
    prompt = '\n+++ '
    intro = '\n by that remembered or with that forgot.'
    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi4.init_manager()
    Prompt().cmdloop()
```